# webpack not including file in bundle

Tags: webpack, pdf.js

Webpack is not including a dependency of a dependency.
This leaf dependency is required using `require('entry?name-of-dep')`.

And `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader'
      },
      {
        exclude: [/\.html$/, /(node_modules|bower_components)/],
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: 'es2015',
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

In the output bundle, the dependency missing is as:

```
/* 38 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    /* (ignored) */

/***/ }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: See discussion at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/7165

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @async5, it was a regression: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/7165

And it would be necessary to manually add the workerSrc path:
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/webpack/main.js#L11

And create the bundle separately:
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/webpack/webpack.config.js#L8